# Grouping map by similar (not identical) keys

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have

```
Map<Foo, Bar> m;
m.put(foo1, bar1);
m.put(foo2, bar2);
```

a method to check if keys are similar:

```
boolean isSimilar(Foo foo1, Foo foo2);
```

I would like to group the values of entries if keys are similar.
If foo1 is similar to foo2 I would like to group value into a new map:

```
Map<foo1, {bar1,bar2}>
```

Is it possible to use a groupingBy collector where the grouping is not performed on identical keys but on similar keys?

I would like to run this process in parallel. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define similar?  From a `HashMap` perspective, keys are equal if they compare equally via the `equals` method.  It is up to you what attributes are included or excluded to return true when comparing `equal` objects.  So, what exactly constitutes similar objects?  Also in your example, which `similar` object do you chose as the `key`?

Comment: If you use a method `T similar(Foo foo){}` for grouping and ensure that the equal value of T is returned for your "similar" objects, you would be able to achieve it.

Comment: @WJS. Example: if Foo is a String, similar Foos share 90% character identity.

Comment: @Naman. It works. I move isSimilar to equals. To force equals calls instead hashCode() returns a constant value.  The lost in performance calling equals is compensated by parallelism. Is it safe to return constant from hashCode() in this case?

Comment: Not really easy to comment without looking at the implementation and the design preferred.

Comment: @Naman. It's working - Thanks